# Convert 1982 RFC822 to ISO 8601 Date Format using Yahoo Pipes

Tags: date, rss, format, pipe, rfc822

RSS feed

http://www.tides.info/rss.xml?locid=13419

Pipe

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=7639d7857574ee6f8677d59da4dded83

Trying to put daily tide information on a site.  The date format that the RSS feed uses is not recognized by pipes. I am wanting to convert the date from RFC822 to ISO 8601 or some other format that is usable.  Im wanting to display the day's tides(i.e. Saturday) on Saturday. Presently it is displaying two days ahead of time.

Thanks